# Add text on wordpress admin login page

Tags: wp-login-form

I want to add a text in admin login page, i searched a lot about this but can't find any thing else a plugin (its my last option).

I also use this filter:

```
function my_login_logo_url_title() {
    return 'Your Site Name and Info';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

But nothing happen is there any other hook or filter please tell me its urgent.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=login&post_type%5B0%5D=wp-parser-hook&paged=2

Comment: Where ***exactly*** are you trying to add additional text? The header title is the attribute you see when you hover over the header logo, it's not additional text.  Sadly there are very few places on the login page that you can add text.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating custom WordPress login page using

```
<?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
```

Place on the page template the title you wish and the site information then call the login form.

Alternatively(*I have not tested this!*) adding information in the form area by passing the information you want to add in an array.  It will look something like :

```
<?php

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => admin_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_title'    => __( 'Site Title' ),//Displayed in the login form
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
        'remember' => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
} else { // If logged in:
    wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
    echo " | ";
    wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_login_message() {
$message = "Your custom message goes here";
return $message;
}
add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```